# Is it possible to set up auto indent for Django/html templates in WebStorm?

Tags: python, html, django, webstorm, code-formatting

Problem: When I auto intent it removes all indentation any markup/python logic in the template.

Is there a plugin to afford auto indent for Django templates? If not, how can I edit the `Auto-indent Lines` command `⌃⌥I` to support formatting described below:

**index.html:**

```
{% block title %}
  {# note the indent here with django logic #}
  {% render title_tag with title="Sign up Now" global=global %}
{% endblock %}

{% block description %}
  {# note the indent here with html markup #}
  <meta name="description" content="Sign up today with our product.">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{# note the indent here If statement #}
{% if true %}
  <section class="section">
    <p> here too</p> 
  </section>
  {% if false %}
    <div>
      <p>wowo</p>
    </div>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I *really* doubt anything can be done here using any bundled/default stuff. In order to format such stuff more-or-less properly (e.g. keep indentation in blocks) IDE must understand Django tags. [WEB-7814](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7814) ticket is asking just about that (star/vote/comment to get notified on any progress). Right now I may only suggest to try to install "Twig Support" plugin (should work with WebStorm) -- it uses very similar syntax so should help here. Otherwise -- PyCharm or IntelliJ with Python plugin

Comment: Ayeee that was good enough! thanks!

Comment: That really help @LazyOne If you wanna make it an answer I'll mark it correct and upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

In order to format such stuff more-or-less properly (e.g. keep indentation inside blocks) IDE must understand Django tags. [WEB-7814 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7814) is asking just about that (star/vote/comment to get notified on any progress).

Right now I may only suggest to try to **install "Twig Support" plugin** (should work with WebStorm). Twig uses very similar syntax (inspired by Django) so it *should* help here. Otherwise -- PyCharm or full IntelliJ with Python plugin.

---

---

### Twig plugin: Installation Guide for Plugins + Formatting + Usage

- Open: Main menu > Webstorm > Preferences
- Search for "Plugin"

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

- Install Twig Support.
- Restart Webstorm.
- Open: Main menu > Webstorm > Preferences.
- Search "Twig"
- Go to Editor > Code Style > Twig
  [image: Step 4]
- Set tab size and indentation to 2.
- Press apply.
- Search for "File Types"
- Click on "Editor > File Types"
  [image: Step 5]
- Go to "Twig inside of "Recognized File Types" Pane.
  [image: Step 6]
- Click the "+" and add "*.html" "*.tpl" *Note: You may get an error saying this file extensions are already
  used else where.  Override the previous use.*

[image: Step 7]

- Click Apply.
- Restart Webstorm.

[image: Auto indent]